# Add metadata to existing image URL without reading image into memory?

Tags: ios, swift, url, uikit, phasset

For `UIImages` I am writing images with EXIF/IPTC/etc meta using `Photos` like:

```
let dataBundle = mergeImageData(...)
let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
let assetOptions = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
assetOptions.originalFilename =  "\(fileName)"
assetChangeRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: dataBundle, options: assetOptions)
    
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    ...
})

func mergeImageData(image: UIImage, with metadata: NSDictionary) -> Data {}
```

But my app works with images that are potentially too large to read into memory and saves the image to Photos with a `URL` not a `Data` representation:

```
let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, fileURL: imageFileURL, options: options)
```

I don't see any `.meta` option for adding a resource which seems like a shame. Is there anyway to add meta to an existing resource without reading it as a `Data` or `UIImage`?

Comment: Did you try to use `CGImageSource`? it's old, but imo quite efficient. And yes, it allows you to load image from URL (and gives access to image metadata). See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html (it's obj-c, but you will get the idea)

Comment: Thanks but unless I'm missing something that seems to be creating a CGImage in memory from a URL.

Comment: Yes, except it manages them in decent way... But I get your point: you want to manipulate a file without loading it into memory. In that case I'm afraid none of the image-processing libraries would do. I guess you could look for C or C++ library that manipulates the content of the file, based on image format specs (like this one: https://libexif.github.io/).

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I have some code in Objective-C that can update an image's caption (within the image's metadata) and it only needs a URL. The image itself is not loaded into memory. I can post it as an answer if you can read Objective-C code. It should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks I think that sounds helpful. I don't mind obj-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is some code I have from an Objective-C project that is an extension to `NSURL` for getting and setting an image's caption. The code uses some lower level CoreGraphics code to read and write the image metadata without the need to load the image itself into memory. After the Objective-C code (which is working in a production app) I will post my the minimally tested Swift version of the code. One quick test with the Swift code worked. The Photos app was able to display the caption set on an image that was then saved to the photo library using a `UIActivityViewController`.

Setting a `nil` caption removes any existing caption.

BTW - this is the image caption that can be viewed and edited when viewing photos in the Photos app. If you set a caption with this code on an image and then save the image to the photo library then you will be able to see the caption. Or if you import an image from the photo library then this code can access the image's caption if it has one.

Objective-C code:

NSURL+Caption.h

```objectivec
@interface NSURL (Caption)

- (nullable NSString *)imageCaption;
- (BOOL)setImageCaption:(nullable NSString *)caption;

@end
```

NSURL+Caption.m

```objectivec
// The following two functions are shared with the NSURL category and an NSData category
static NSString *imageCaption(CGImageSourceRef source) {
    NSString *caption = nil;

    if (source) {
        CGImageMetadataRef meta = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(source, 0, nil);
        CFRelease(source);
        if (meta) {
            //NSLog(@"meta: %@", meta);
            CGImageMetadataTagRef descTag = CGImageMetadataCopyTagWithPath(meta, nil, CFSTR("dc:description"));
            if (descTag) {
                CFTypeRef descVal = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(descTag);
                NSObject *val = CFBridgingRelease(descVal);
                if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    caption = (NSString *)val;
                } else if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                    NSArray *caps = (NSArray *)val;
                    CGImageMetadataTagRef descRef = (__bridge CGImageMetadataTagRef)(caps.firstObject);
                    if (descRef) {
                        CFTypeRef desc = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(descRef);
                        NSString *comment = CFBridgingRelease(desc);
                        if ([comment isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                            caption = comment;
                        }
                    }
                }
                CFRelease(descTag);
            }
            CFRelease(meta);
        }
    }

    return caption;
}

static BOOL setImageCaption(NSString *caption, CGImageSourceRef source, CGImageDestinationRef dest) {
    BOOL res = NO;
    CGMutableImageMetadataRef meta = CGImageMetadataCreateMutable();

    NSArray *capTags = @[];
    if (caption.length) {
        CGImageMetadataTagRef capTag = CGImageMetadataTagCreate(kCGImageMetadataNamespaceDublinCore, kCGImageMetadataPrefixDublinCore, CFSTR("[x-default]"), kCGImageMetadataTypeString, (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)(caption));
        //NSLog(@"capTag: %@", capTag);
        capTags = @[ CFBridgingRelease(capTag) ];
    }
    CGImageMetadataTagRef descTag = CGImageMetadataTagCreate(kCGImageMetadataNamespaceDublinCore, kCGImageMetadataPrefixDublinCore, CFSTR("description"), kCGImageMetadataTypeArrayOrdered, (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)(capTags));
    CGImageMetadataSetTagWithPath(meta, nil, CFSTR("dc:description"), descTag);
    CFRelease(descTag);
    //NSLog(@"new meta: %@", meta);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), 2, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(options, kCGImageDestinationMergeMetadata, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFDictionarySetValue(options, kCGImageDestinationMetadata, meta);
    CFErrorRef error;
    if (!CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource(dest, source, options, &error)) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    } else {
        // Finalize isn't to be used with CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource. Using it prints an error to the console
        // even though the image caption is updated properly.
        //CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
        res = YES;
    }
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(meta);

    return res;
}

@implementation NSURL (Caption)

- (nullable NSString *)imageCaption {
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)self, nil);
    //NSLog(@"%@", self);
    return imageCaption(source);
}

- (BOOL)setImageCaption:(nullable NSString *)caption {
    BOOL res = NO;
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)self, nil);
    if (source) {
        CFStringRef uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
        CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)self, uti, 1, NULL);
        if (dest) {
            if (setImageCaption(caption, source, dest)) {
                res = YES;
            }
            CFRelease(dest);
        }

        CFRelease(source);
    }

    return res;
}

@end
```

---

The Swift translation:

```swift
private func getImageCaption(from source: CGImageSource) -> String? {
    var caption: String? = nil

    if let meta = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(source, 0, nil) {
        if let descTag = CGImageMetadataCopyTagWithPath(meta, nil, "dc:description" as CFString) {
            let descVal = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(descTag)
            if let str = descVal as? String {
                caption = str
            } else if let caps = descVal as? [CGImageMetadataTag] {
                if let descRef = caps.first {
                    let desc = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(descRef)
                    if let comment = desc as? String {
                        caption = comment
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return caption
}

private func setImageCaption(_ caption: String?, source: CGImageSource, destination: CGImageDestination) -> Bool {
    var res = false

    var meta = CGImageMetadataCreateMutable()
    var capTags: [CGImageMetadataTag] = []
    if let caption, !caption.isEmpty {
        if let capTag = CGImageMetadataTagCreate(kCGImageMetadataNamespaceDublinCore, kCGImageMetadataPrefixDublinCore, "[x-default]" as CFString, .string, caption as CFTypeRef) {
            capTags = [ capTag ]
        }
    }
    if let descTag = CGImageMetadataTagCreate(kCGImageMetadataNamespaceDublinCore, kCGImageMetadataPrefixDublinCore, "description" as CFString, .arrayOrdered, capTags as CFTypeRef) {
        CGImageMetadataSetTagWithPath(meta, nil, "dc:description" as CFString, descTag)
    }

    let options = [ kCGImageDestinationMergeMetadata : true, kCGImageDestinationMetadata : meta ] as CFDictionary
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    if CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource(destination, source, options, &error) {
        res = true
    } else {
        print("Can't copy image info: \(error)")
    }

    return res
}

extension URL {
    var imageCaption: String? {
        get {
            if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(self as CFURL, nil) {
                return getImageCaption(from: source)
            } else {
                // Probably means the URL isn't for an image
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(self as CFURL, nil) {
                if let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source),
                   let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(self as CFURL, uti, 1, nil) {
                    _ = setImageCaption(newValue, source: source, destination: destination)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll report back after I get something implemented.

Comment: Tried out the Swift, everything compiles. It reads an existing comment, but writing it didn't have any effect in the Caption. I checked the tags and don't see the new tag value anywhere.

Comment: Guess I'll try the objective-c now.

Comment: I was just able to test the Swift code. It worked perfectly for me. I obtained a URL for an image. Called `imageURL.imageCaption = "Test"`. Then I called `print(imageURL.imageCaption)` and got back "Test". I then saved the image to the photo library (using a UIActivityViewController) and then viewed the image in the Photos app and I could see the caption. So I'm not sure what tool you are using to view the metadata but the Photos app is happy with the Swift code I posted.

Comment: I see, yeah I didn't save the file again - was thinking it just modified it. Will try thanks. Oh, and you're sure it's not reading the image into memory at any point?

Comment: Thanks for the note about the caption, yes I am aware of where you can see it and check it, but since I didn't, I looked at all the tags.

Comment: You don't need to save the file again. Calling `imageCaption` updates the contents of the image file pointed to by the URL. Saving the updated image to the photos library is just a test to verify that the Photos app can read the newly set caption. I haven't done a real analysis of the memory footprint of the code I posted but I'm reasonably sure the APIs being used only read and write the metadata. There's no need for it to read the image data into memory.

Comment: Sorry - it was user error. Seems fine thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to sniff out other CGImageMetadataSetTags like for the User Comment?

Comment: It's a matter of researching the path of the various metadata you want. Look at the docs for `CGImageMetadata`. There is a method for enumerating tags. Try it on an image that has relevant tags to use as a guide. I think things are easier for standard EXIF data. The caption used by Photos is actually more of a special case than a lot of the more standard stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Its just I've been working with EXIF/IPTC etc this last week but this looks a bit different. It would be nice to get the User Comment which is the other most popular tag besides the caption.

Comment: Like for the caption I've been using `kCGImagePropertyIPTCCaptionAbstract` and the user comment is `kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment`